# xml data from API has multiple undefined name spaces - how to use xslt to display it in html?

Tags: javascript, xml, xslt

I am using a REST api to get XML data from a database and am trying to display it in an html format using xslt. Unfortunately the xml data comes back with a few namespaces that are not defined. I can get the style sheet to work just fine on a local copy of the data if I strip the namespaces or define them. Striping the name spaces feels like a hack and no the correct way to do this.

this is essentially an example of the data I get back:

```
<root>
<entity:Entity ns1:atrib="foo">
    <g:Value>foo1</g:value>
    <g:Name>fooName</g:Name>
</entity:Entity>
```

xmlhttprequest methods in JS to get this information and XSLTProcessor to transform it then add it into a . It's not displaying the transformed information and i'm 100% positive it's the namespaces that is causing the issue.

I've googled everything I can think of with no luck. Road blocks like this are almost always due to me missing something fundamental.

Comment: You should fix the server side code to return valid XML.

Comment: changing the server side code is not at all an option what so ever.

Answer (score 0):

XSLT will only operate on XML that is well-formed, and it requires all namespaces to be declared. If you want to process this data you should ideally fix it at source; if you can't do that you need to repair it before processing.

There are some XML parsers that allow you to process non-namespace-aware XML, and you could use such a parser as the basis of your repair tool, but this is such an unusual requirement that I'll have to leave you to research how to do that yourself.

Comment: Yea no control over the source, i will just need to define the name spaces some how manually or strip them out.